# correct linux kernel configuration for hotplug

Tags: linux, embedded, linux-kernel

i am using busybox and linux 2.6.32.4.
my configuration is based on fedora 12. and started mdev according  to mdev document. but i cant see my modules like network adapters and plugged usb devices. is there thing must be done?
mdev commands (after mounts):

```
echo /sbin/mdev > /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug
/sbin/mdev -s
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the output of `which mdev`?  According to the [BusyBox documentation](http://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html), mdev is in /bin and not /sbin.

Assuming that mdev is correctly activated, can you verify that hotplug is configured in the kernel you are using?  It would be the `CONFIG_HOTPLUG` line in the kernel's configuration file.  You may be able to check **/proc/config.gz*** depending on the kernel's configuration.

Assuming that mdev is correctly activated and hotplug is enabled in the kernel, your problem may be in mdev's configuration file **/etc/mdev.conf**.

Another thing that may be helpful would be setting /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug to a shell script that logs the environment and command line it is invoked with.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $* >> /tmp/hotplug.log
env >> /tmp/hotplug.log
```